# GWT-HighCharts only partially showing series unless zoomed. (Internet Explorer only)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt, highcharts

I am using GWT-Highcharts in a web application. It is important to not the following about my issue:
- The issue exists SOLELY in internet explorer. (Im running 10 and being told 8 and 9 are the same issue)
- The range of days I am pulling is one month. 10/01-10/31
- If I pull just 10/1-10/28, it seems to render the entire series.

I have searched google repeatedly. I have read documentation and many posts regarding IE issues. None of them touch on this issue.

I cannot even begin to have a clue why the points arent DRAWN unless you zoom in.

Any help would be appreciated. Again, these charts work great in FireFox and Chrome.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Snippet 1:

```
chart = new Chart()
                .setChartTitleText("EmNet Sensor Chart for " + titleDate)  
                .setZoomType(Chart.ZoomType.X_AND_Y)
                .setToolTip(new ToolTip()
                    .setValueDecimals(2))
                .setExporting(exporting.setFilename("chart_" + new Date().getTime()))
                .setCredits(credits)
                .setAnimation(false);
```

Snippet 2:

```
Series series = chart.createSeries()
                       .setName(Descr[1] + " - " + Units[1])
                       .setYAxis(0)
                       .setXAxis(0)
                       .setPoints(new Number[][] {})
                       .setPlotOptions(new AreaPlotOptions()
                                .setColor("#FF0000")
                               .setMarker(new Marker()
                                       .setEnabled(false))
                               .setShadow(false)
                               .setAnimation(false)
                               .setHoverStateEnabled(false)
                               .setStickyTracking(false));
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? Also, try to disable animations in your charts.

Comment: No errors in the console, and animations are already disabled.

Comment: Both, `series.animation` and `chart.animation` ?

Comment: Correct, see the edits to my question.

Comment: May also be important to know, that because of the way that the Web Application was developed, it forces IE to use IE5:Quirks mode. It is the only way that the web app is drawn properly. I believe because of this, the highcharts code is being executed as pre-IE8 and using the VML wrapper.

Comment: Right, sorry, animations are disabled. Regarding IE5 - it's not supported bu Highcharts, see [compatibility page](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility).

Comment: I am running IE10, and when I force a mode for IE7 or higher, it still reacts the same way.

Comment: Could you show that error live (page/jsFiddle)? Se we can investigate this.